# Write to multiple cells in Google sheets

Tags: javascript

is there anyway to write to multiple cells with just one line of code?

Instead of:

```
response_sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Name");
response_sheet.getRange("B6").setValue("Evaluators:");
response_sheet.getRange("A9").setValue("Ownership");
```

something like:

```
response_sheet.getRange([["B1"],["B6"],["A9"]]).setValues([["Name","Evaluators","Ownership"]]);
```

The above gets me a "Range not found" error though. Cant find any working samples or documentation on whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think that there are no methods to directly import values to the discrete ranges in Class SpreadsheetApp. But if you want to import "Name","Evaluators" and "Ownership" to "B1","B6" and "A9" using `getRange()` and `setValues()`, you can use the following sample script.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B9").setValues([["","Name"],["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""],["","Evaluators"],["",""],["",""],["Ownership",""]]);
```

If you want to use the method with higher readability, how about using Sheets API v4? In order to use this script, please enable Sheets API v4 at Advanced Google Services and API console.

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Google Sheets API v4

#### [Enable Sheets API v4 at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sheets.googleapis.com/)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "sheets". And click Google Sheets API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

#### One liner sample :

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({"data":[["sheet1!B1","Name"],["sheet1!B6","Evaluators"],["sheet1!A9","Ownership"]].map(function(e){return{"range":e[0],"values":[[e[1]]]}}),"valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED"},"### spreadsheet ID ###");
```

#### Expanded one liner sample :

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(
  {
    "data":[
      ["sheet1!B1","Name"], // Please input range (a1notation) and value.
      ["sheet1!B6","Evaluators"], // Please input range (a1notation) and value.
      ["sheet1!A9","Ownership"] // Please input range (a1notation) and value.
    ].map(function(e){
      return{
        "range":e[0],
        "values":[[e[1]]]
      }
    }),
    "valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED"
  },
  "### spreadsheet ID ###" // Please input spreadsheet ID.
);
```

#### Note :

- When you use this script, please input the ranges which are a1notation and values to above 2 dimensional array, and also spreadsheet ID.
- When you use `["sheet1!B1","value1"],["sheet2!B1","value2"]`, you can import values to both sheets.

#### References :

- Advanced Google Services : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- Sheets API v4: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

If this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.